# SELECT for List of course a person has not taken, using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I know the list of courses available and list of courses a person has taken.
How can I SELECT/output the courses a person has not taken in the following in comma separated format,

```
SELECT to list all courses:
SELECT DISTINCT(COURSE) FROM tblCOURSE

SELECT to list all courses taken by user
SELECT DISTINCT(COURSE) FROM tblCOURSE WHERE pid='XXXXX'
```

I would like to use the `LISTAGG(COURSETYPE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pid,course)` to list them as `COURSE2,COURSE4,COURSE5,COURSE6,COURSE7,.

Example:
Say list of courses available is:
`COURSE1,COURSE2,COURSE3,COURSE4,COURSE5,COURSE6,COURSE7,COURSE8`

List of courses taken by person `XXXXX` is:
`COURSE1,COURSE3,COURSE8`

The SELECT output/result should be:

```
 PID         COURSES
--------------------------------------------------
 XXXXX    COURSE2,COURSE4,COURSE5,COURSE6,COURSE7`
--------------------------------------------------
```

where `COURSES` is the list of course pid `XXXXX` has NOT taken.

Comment: :Can Explain in a better way with data .why you have put a filter of `coursetype='ZZZ'`

Comment: @Gaurav the filter COURSETYPE is not really needed. Let me try and explain it further.

Comment: The data model here is not normalized; it appears that rows in your `tblCOURSE` table each represent a "course taken by a user"; your query `SELECT DISTINCT course FROM tblCOURSE` does not list all courses, it lists all courses that have at least one student. If the institution offers a course not taken by any users, it wouldn't appear in the table (I presume); so your model won't be able to accurately answer the question "which courses has user X NOT taken?".

Answer (score 2):

```
create table tblcourse(pid number,course varchar2(20));


Insert into TBLCOURSE  (PID, COURSE) Values (1, 'COURSE1');
Insert into TBLCOURSE  (PID, COURSE) Values (1, 'COURSE3');
Insert into TBLCOURSE  (PID, COURSE) Values (1, 'COURSE5');
Insert into TBLCOURSE  (PID, COURSE) Values (2, 'COURSE8');
Insert into TBLCOURSE  (PID, COURSE) Values (3, 'COURSE8');
Insert into TBLCOURSE  (PID, COURSE) Values (4, 'COURSE2');
Insert into TBLCOURSE  (PID, COURSE) Values (5, 'COURSE4');
Insert into TBLCOURSE  (PID, COURSE) Values (5, 'COURSE6');
COMMIT;
```

**QUERY :**

```
WITH TAB AS 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT(COURSE) as course  
   FROM tblcourse --distinct courses  
MINUS   
 SELECT DISTINCT(COURSE) as course  
  FROM tblcourse 
 WHERE pid=:pid --will give you distinct courses that pid subscribe
)
SELECT  :pid,LISTAGG(COURSE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COURSE) as courses 
  FROM TAB;
```

*Result as you want :* `pass pid as 1`

```
PID           COURSES
-------------------------
 1            COURSE2,COURSE4,COURSE6,COURSE8
```

[Tried out example in SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c02f8/1)

**EDIT**

*I can't think a better solution for this ,may be someone can suggest a better way to do this ,in the mean while you can have a look to this,but sometimes cartesian product rocks:)*

```
WITH course_cartesian as (
       SELECT pid,course 
         FROM (SELECT DISTINCT course 
                 FROM tblcourse)q1,
              (SELECT DISTINCT pid 
                 FROM tblcourse)q2 
             ORDER BY pid,course
   )
,tbl_course AS(SELECT pid,course 
                 FROM course_cartesian
                MINUS
              SELECT pid,course FROM tblcourse
              )
SELECT pid,listagg(course,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY course) as courses 
  FROM   tbl_course  
 GROUP BY pid 
 ORDER BY pid;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: output]

SQLFIDDLE[link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c02f8/2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why are we hard coding the pid in the SQLFIDDLE example? We should be showing the pid as a part of the result too.

Comment: @Ram:If i am not mistaken,you're going to pass `pid` to your query and you'll be getting the result for that pid ,and i have used bind variable ,its not `hardcoded`  `WHERE pid=:pid ` --here pid is passed by you

Comment: @Ram:Or do you want data for all the pid who have not taken the course ? If that please specify

Comment: -Yes it has to be for all pids who have not taken the course.

Comment: @Ram:You can see my edit part ,i am not saying that this is the best way to get the desired result.May be someone will have a better way of solving this.

Answer (score 0):

The base select would be something like:

```
SELECT :pid, LISTAGG(C, ',') WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY course FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT(COURSE) as C FROM tblCOURSE
  MINUS
  SELECT DISTINCT(COURSE) as C FROM tblCOURSE WHERE pid=:pid
)
```

Replace :pid with the id you are looking up.

(This is untested, I've looked up the LISTAGG syntax online)

Comment: :your approach is correct ,only change needed is  `WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY C`  not `course`